# SQL query relational tables

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

I am a novice to working with databases, So I am hoping you guys will forgive my perhaps silly basic question, that said, I am trying to create relational tables using PHPMyadmin.

I have two tables: **chapters** in which I create `chapters ( ID, position, visible)` , the other table **pages** in which I create pages `(ID, chapters_id, position, visible )`

What I want to do is connect pages to specific chapters by saying page with `chapters_id` equal to `chapters ID` belong together.

how do I query that?

```
SELECT chapters_id 
FROM pages 
WHERE chapters_id = chapters.ID ???
```

thank you!

Comment: Hint:  `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, I will dive right into INNER JOIN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use inner join between two tables
 - A JOIN clause is used to combine rows from two or more tables, based
   on a related column between them

```
select c.*,p.* from chapters c inner join pages p on c.ID= p.chapters_id
```

Comment: @Bee do you want to know about inner join working procedure

Comment: that would be great! I am working on a project in which I will have to do a lot of relational tables, so yes please!

Comment: @Bee https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp please read this site example is very helpful if need more i can direct assist you via skype or anything else

Answer (score 2):

Just to confirm i understood your question, you are trying to connect chapters to pages.

The way you would do it is

```
select c.id, p.chapters_id 
from chapters c join pages p 
     on c.id = p.chapters_id
```

If you would like to limit the pages that fall under the first chapter the way you would do is

```
select c.id, p.chapters_id 
from chapters c join pages p 
     on c.id = p.chapters_id
where p.chapters_id =1
```

This join is know as an inner join

It is ASNI SQL compliant meaning, it would work in any ANSI SQL compliant databases like SQL Server, Oracle just to mention a few